# Setting multiple checkbox values with form_set_value

Tags: forms, taxonomy-terms

I have a field that is a taxonomy term reference with a checkbox widget that allows multiple values.

I am looping through a json structure, finding the associated code value and then setting the value on the checkbox widget in the form with a case statement.

My problem is it's only setting the last value, not all the values. Here is the code. In this case where the hosts array contains all three values, I would expect all checkboxes associated with all three taxonomy terms to be checked. Only the last one is checked.

```
//json structure
"hosts": [
    {
        "alias": "external",
        "url": "abc.com"
    },
    {
        "alias": "internal",
        "url": "abc.com"
    }
    {
        "alias": "local",
        "url": "abc.com"
    }
] 

          //php
          $hosts = $response->{'hosts'};

           foreach($hosts as $host){

           $alias = $host->alias;

            switch($alias){
                case "external":
                    form_set_value($form['field_proxy_host'], array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(0 => array('tid' => '758'))), $form_state);
                break;
                case "internal":
                    form_set_value($form['field_proxy_host'], array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(0 => array('tid' => '759'))), $form_state);
                break;
                case "local":
                    form_set_value($form['field_proxy_host'], array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(0 => array('tid' => '760'))), $form_state);
                break;

            }


        }
```

Comment: Where does the $host variable come from?

Comment: I updated the code to better reflect hosts. It's actually an api call that returns a json object .

Comment: form_set_value sets the value, it does not append the value to the values already there. Each time you call form_set_value it clears the previous values and sets the value to your new value.

Comment: What you are doing doesnt really make sense because of cause will the variable be overwritten. The same variable cannot have three different values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to pass an array with all values to `form_set_value()` as the function is setting the value, not appending to it. I would alter your setup to build an array of values with your switch/foreach block and then pass that array in a single `form_set_value` call below the switch, outside of the foreach.

Update your your foreach / switch like so:

```
$host_values = [];
foreach($hosts as $host){
  switch($host->alias){
    case "external":
      $host_values[] = ['tid' => '758'];
      break;
    case "internal":
      $host_values[] = ['tid' => '759']
      break;
    case "local":
      $host_values[] = ['tid' => '760']
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}

form_set_value($form['field_proxy_host'], [LANGUAGE_NONE => $host_values], $form_state);
```

Comment: OK, any idea on how to do that in form_set_value? For my value parameter? If I add to another array say $hosts_values ('758', '759', '760') //numbers being tid's, how do I pass those as a group to be set in value?

Comment: Updated my answer with the code example for your use case. Basically you build an array of the `$host_values` and then you pass that array into `$form_set_value()` as seen above. In your original post you are building this array manually each time you call form_set_value, but the array always only had a single value, e.g. `array(0 => array('tid' => '758')))`.

Comment: Sure, np. You should accept the answer so it shows as resolved. :)